# Check multiple values in multiple columns mysql

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

I have database structure like one shown in following image. My table name is compare_analytics

[image: database structure]

I know how to check a single value against multiple columns. Example like one below:

```
SELECT * FROM `compare_analytics` WHERE '1MB20D-060' IN (igbt1,igbt2,igbt3)
```

I want to check multiple columns against multiple values. Like, I want to select all rows in which `IRG4BC30FD` and `IRG4BC30FD` **igbt** are present their position in row doesn't matter. They can be in **igbt1**, **igbt2** or **igbt3** on any of the column.
Query should select rows with id 4,5, and 6 ideally because these values are present in these rows.

I am looking for a query without `OR` clause, I know that can be achieved with `OR` clause, but there should be some shorter way to do this.

Comment: because of how your table is set up, there is no other way to do that.  You have to use the OR clause.  If, however, you redesign your table and data, then you will have other options.  As Strawberry mentioned, look up SQL Table Normalization

Comment: No other way...unless you do some dynamic sql, which gets REALLY messy and is most likely not the way you want to go.

Comment: What shorter way can be used given that there are three separate and different  columns to check? As has already been mentioned, changing the database structure is the only viable way of changing the 'lookup'.

Comment: Can you please tell me how my table structure should be ?

Comment: How should I write solution using OR clause ?

Comment: Write it exactly as you explained it: (igbt1 = 'IRG4BC30FD' AND igbt2 = IRG4BC30FD) OR (igbt2 = 'IRG4BC30FD' AND igbt1 = IRG4BC30FD) OR.... - covering EVERY permutation (now you know why everyone's telling you the database design is bad). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS compare_analytics;

 CREATE TABLE compare_analytics
 (igbt       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
 ,type INT NOT NULL
 ,PRIMARY KEY(igbt,type)
 );

 INSERT INTO compare_analytics VALUES
 ('1MB20D-040',1),
 ('1MB20D-050',2),
 ('1MB20D-060',3);

 SELECT * 
   FROM compare_analytics
  WHERE igbt IN ('1MB20D-040','1MB20D-060');

 +------------+------+
 | igbt       | type |
 +------------+------+
 | 1MB20D-040 |    1 |
 | 1MB20D-060 |    3 |
 +------------+------+
```

Comment: I have a lot of respect, however, are you suggesting that most of the table design in this database is correct and they only need to change this one table?

Comment: @RyanVincent In the comments above, the OP has requested an example of a normalized design; so I've provided one. That's all.